# How do I run Ant from PHP

Tags: php, ant, batch-file

I am executing a batch file which runs ant commands. The batch file is executed through PHP and I am using XAMPP. Although when I double click the batch file it works when I execute it via PHP it simply doesn't recognize the ant component.

the batch file essentially looks as following

```
cd C:\Users\Me\File
ant release
```

and I am running it with PHP function exec()

Can someone tell me the problem?

Comment: Have you tried instead of `ant` putting in the full path to `ant`. IE `C:\Path\To\Ant\Exe\ant release`?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem might be this path:

```
cd C:\Users\Me\File
```

PHP process most likely doesn't have the permission to access your user folder.